# Get IE proxy settings from action script

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

In our product we use a small flash applet for realtime communication with server application (rpc).
We sell this product to corporative clients with internal security police, sometimes strange :) 
As i known (but not sure) flash socket connect to specified host directly, using system (or intranet) proxy settings, if needed. This is suit us, but in one company, proxy settings set directly in browser (IE), and system proxy block any external requests. 
To prevent this, we need teach our applet understand IE (and, if it is possible, any browser) proxy settings and communicate with our application throught it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No way, you can not detect the current browser's proxy settings.

The solution could be adding an option window to your application. In this case, users can define new proxy entries and your application can use it.